# Weak reference callback is not called

Tags: python

The callback assigned to a weak reference object is not called when the strong reference is destroyed, the .**callback** attribute confirms the function was assigned. Why is it not being called?

It seems the weak reference to the function Foo.bar is not destroyed when the strong reference is destroyed, why?

```
def is_dead(wr): 
    print("Callback function called!")

class Foo(object):
    def bar(self): pass
 
method = Foo.bar
wr = weakref.ref(method, is_dead)
method = None
print(wr.__callback__)
```

Comment: Maybe you're confused about what a strong reference is? Strong references are just increments in an objects reference count. They don't live in memory, you can't tell one strong reference from another, and Python can't tell you when a particular one is destroyed. All it can tell you is when _all_ strong reference have been destroyed, which is what your code is detecting here.

Comment: after removing "a reference" `method`, `Foo.bar` it still exists though right?

Comment: In your code set `method = Foo()` and run it again. When you set `method = None` you will remove the last strong reference to instance `method` and your callback should be called.

Comment: My question is what other references are there to Foo.bar aside from the method variable?

Comment: Yes but im asking about Foo.bar method, why is it not garbage collected?